# Is there a formula to calculate starting hand ranking?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, starting-hand

I'm about to do some research with Nash tables, now I want to create an equity heatmap for the starting hands.

Is there any canonical way to calculate their relative rank? Perhaps a conventional source?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no "generic" way of calculating the equity of a given confrontation except for calculating it directly. For example, bigger pairs have a 4:1-ish advantage over smaller pairs, but the odds are not exactly the same in AA-KK than in AA-77. As a rule of thumb, with round numbers:

Bigger pair vs two lower cards (paired or not): 80%

A pocket pair vs two unpaired overcards: 50%

A pocket pair vs two cards (one higher, one lower or equal): 65%

A pair dominating two unpaired cards (like 99 vs 94): 90%

Two unpaired high cards vs two unpaired low cards: 60%

Dominating unpaired hand (like AK vs AJ): 70%

Comment: You can calculate the range of the hand vs. any two, taking the blockers of that hand into account.

Comment: Sure. But your equity against a random hand is not necessarely a good criterion for "hand ranking"

Comment: Well, then what is? The only reason AA is on the top is because it has the most equity. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: Why equity against one random hand and not against two, or three? Or equity against the Nash equilibrium calling range in a given spot? AA is still best in all of those spots

Comment: Because OP asked if you could calculate the best starting hands. That means you have to compare each hand to all other possible hands.

Comment: @Jonast92 Why only on a 1vs1 basis? Multiway spots also happen in poker

Comment: i never said 1vs1 basis. I mean hand vs entire range.

Comment: Also, your answer is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @Jonast92 You are talking about the range of 1 player. Why not 2 or 3 players simultaneously?